# How is windows 7 able to recover from a driver crash?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, crash, display-driver

I noticed that my brother's gaming PC running Windows 7 had a driver crash for his nvidia 690 video card, but the OS itself didn't crash, rather it claimed that it had recovered.  I was curious how this is possible?  I was under the impression that since the kernel has no memory protection a driver crash would bring down the whole OS, which I am basing off my knowledge of the linux kernel.  How does windows 7 avoid the whole OS crashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Windows Vista and the WDDM driver model, the GPU drivers are splitted in a kernel and user mode part. So an issue in the user mode part doesn't crash the Windows any longer.

The feature you see is called **Timeout Detection and Recovery of GPUs (TDR)**. Microsoft explained [this here in an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487368).

1. > The Video Scheduler component of the Windows Vista graphics stack
   >   detects that the GPU is taking more than the permitted quantum time to
   >   execute the particular task and tries to preempt this particular task.
   >   The preempt operation has a "wait" timeout—the actual "TDR timeout."
   >   This step is thus the "timeout detection" phase of the process. The
   >   default timeout period in Windows Vista is 2 seconds. If the GPU
   >   cannot complete or preempt the current task within the TDR timeout,
   >   then the GPU is diagnosed as hung.
2. > The operating system informs the WDDM driver that a timeout has been detected and it must 
   >   reset the GPU. The driver is told to stop accessing memory and should
   >   not access hardware after this time. The operating system and the WDDM
   >   driver collect hardware and other state information that could be
   >   useful for post-mortem diagnosis.
3. > The operating system resets the appropriate state of the graphics
   >   stack. The Video Memory Manager component of the graphics stack purges
   >   all allocations from video memory. The WDDM driver resets the GPU
   >   hardware state. The graphics stack takes the final actions and
   >   restores the desktop to the responsive state. As mentioned earlier,
   >   some older DirectX applications may now render just black, and the
   >   user may be required to restart these applications. Well-written
   >   DirectX 9Ex and DirectX 10 applications that handle "Device Remove"
   >   continue to work correctly. The application must release and then
   >   recreate its Microsoft Direct3D device and all of its objects.
   >
   > Throughout the process of GPU hang detection and recovery, the desktop
   >   is unresponsive and thus unavailable to the user. In the final stages
   >   of recovery, a brief screen flash occurs that is similar to the one
   >   when the screen resolution is changed. After the desktop has been
   >   successfully recovered, the following informational message appears to
   >   the user.
   >   [image]

If you see this message too often, check this KB article:

**"Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" error in Windows 7 or Windows Vista**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946/en-us

If you use an AMD GPU, check this article from AMD:

**How to troubleshoot “Display driver stopped responding and has recovered”, ATIKMDAG.sys type errors**

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/737-27116RadeonSeries-ATIKMDAGhasstoppedrespondingerrormessages.aspx

Comment: Several months ago had a same problem and windows recovered automatically. Never figured out how it recovered without me doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

"Crash" is a very broad term. You probably mean this balloon message:

> Display driver stopped responding and has recovered.

It's not very detailed too and you should read it like this:

> Your GPU has done something unexpected but the driver has done some magic to recover it. Don't panic, situation is under control now.

So basically it's not the driver that crashed, but the hardware. Driver has done its best and succeeded. What's going on under the hood when GPU crashes depends on the implementation, but generally the driver is resetting it to make sure it's not in some abnormal state.

I believe GPU crash recovery in this form is supported by Windows since Vista, but I remeber seeing similar automatic recovery on ASUS cards with ATI GPU on XP some 8 years ago, before Vista's release.

Comment: It is indeed the driver, and not the hardware, that has crashed, and Windows has stepped in and restarted the driver. The driver is not necessarily running in kernal mode. My Intel video driver is a user-mode driver, and would crash (meaning otherwise permanently black screen) frequently and randomly thru 3 update versions.

Answer (score 0):

The driver didn't crash, the GPU did. The PC recovered by resetting the GPU.

Comment: It's rather an abuse of language to say the GPU "crashes". Certainly, hardware can malfunction, but any decently-written driver can take most such events in stride. What the Question Asker describes is almost certainly buggy driver software.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure on Win7, but on other systems drivers have a top and a bottom part.  The bottom will most likely crash your whole system because it runs in common memory.  The top runs at a much higher level and it is possible to shield it from damaging other things, and thus for crashes to be detected by out of bounds memory requests, and thus captured before they destroy something else.